# Increment a number inside excel formula sidewise

Tags: excel, formula, auto-increment

I have following numbers in Column D1 to D21

```
1  | 4 | 51 | 4 | 57 | 6 | 16 | 11 | 41 | 3 | 26 | 3 | 27 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 6 | 22 | 6 | 23
```

I want to write a formula which will produce an output like this:

```
6:23    6:22    5:8 5:3 3:27    3:26    11:41   6:16    4:47    4:51    1
```

I have put the following formula on Column P1 and tried dragging on the left side but it is showing the same value in all rows as the value of 1 & 2 is not changing to 3 & 4:

This is what i want:

```
OFFSET($D$1,1,0)&":"&OFFSET($D$1,2,0)
OFFSET($D$1,3,0)&":"&OFFSET($D$1,4,0)
OFFSET($D$1,5,0)&":"&OFFSET($D$1,6,0)
```

The middle value in the above formula should change.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with a smaller range of values and the following should work for you. You'll need to replace $A$1:$I$1 with your range.

`=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,0,COUNT($A$1:$I$1)-(COLUMN()*2))&":"&OFFSET($A$1,0,COUNT($A$1:$I$1)-((COLUMN()*2)-1)),IF((COUNT($A$1:$I$1)+1)=(COLUMN()*2),$A$1,""))`

Also tested with your full range $A$1:$U$1:

`=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,0,COUNT($A$1:$U$1)-(COLUMN()*2))&":"&OFFSET($A$1,0,COUNT($A$1:$U$1)-((COLUMN()*2)-1)),IF((COUNT($A$1:$U$1)+1)=(COLUMN()*2),$A$1,""))`

[image]

Comment: Hello,Thanks for reply. My data is from A1:A26 and not from A1:U1 so will the above formula work?

Comment: Change the range to your range, and then change Column() to Row()